Disable the expansion buttons of the right-click-menu in favor of showing everything at once?
Since a while, in Gnome, when I right click and a menu appears, it looks very strange. A lot of the menu items are hidden behind expansion buttons.
For example to reach for the 'inspect element' option in browsers, i first have to expand the menu to be able to see the items which, I guess to other people, are less popular, maybe? And it is not only in browsers, it is across the entire system everywhere.
However to me, it is a great nuisance because it costs extra clicks to reach what I need. And difficult to understand too, because there is plenty of space in my screen to show everything at once.
Maybe there is a Gnome setting or override that disables all expansion buttons, and makes it show fully always. I believe it is a window manager feature to limit the size of the menus, not a choice that "app" (as they are called apparently) developers make, per se. In fact I noticed now, that the menus always expand from the mouse pointer either up or down depending on which half it is on, and choose to limit based on if there is enough screen space on that side.
Is there an option to make the menu always display everything if possible on the screen size? And while we are at it, maybe make the items a bit smaller?

What Ubuntu version are you using? I don't see Gnome having any say in what menu items are displayed, or how, in any app that I use. Not even the font of the items. It's purely the app that decides that.
